# Hosting Multiple hosts under IIS for WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, wshttpbinding

I need to use multiple hosts under IIS for WCF.
We're using wshttpbinding and we've found NO success so far even after checking out a couple of similar questions on stackoveflow.

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=WebSMS20July;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>

    <!--<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="999999999"
       useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true"
       executionTimeout="459999999" appRequestQueueLimit="99999999" delayNotificationTimeout="999999999"
                  maxWaitChangeNotification="999999999" shutdownTimeout="9999999999"/>-->

    <!--
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace. 

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>-->

        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
 <!--
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"> 

      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>        
        <add prefix="http://localhost:12350"/>

      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <bindings>
       <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="wsHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
             <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
             <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                   establishSecurityContext="false" />
             </security>
          </binding>
          <binding name="NewBinding0" />
       </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
        <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior"
    name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
     bindingName="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1">
     <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
     </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
     bindingName="wsHttpBinding2" contract="WcfService1.IService1"
     listenUri="http://localhost:8090" />
    <host>
     <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://mydomain/mywcfservice/Service1.svc" />
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost/mywcfservice/Service1.svc" />
     </baseAddresses>
    </host>
   </service>
  </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here's my service factory class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace WcfService1
{
    public class CustomHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory 

    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            //CustomHost customServiceHost =
            //  new CustomHost(serviceType, baseAddresses[1]);
            //return customServiceHost;
            ServiceHost host;

            host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses[0]);

            return host;

        }
        class CustomHost : ServiceHost
        {
            public CustomHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
                : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
            { }
            protected override void ApplyConfiguration()
            {
                base.ApplyConfiguration();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Contents of my Service1.svc file

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService1.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" Factory="WcfService1.CustomHostFactory" %>
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Why cant you simply create multiple websites in IIS and run multiple instances of app in multiple hosts?

Comment: I cannot do that since I have 2 types of clients connecting and doing different actions on the same object

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Error messages are helpful in these situations.  What you are doing should work (the second attempt you made with the subclassed ServiceHost is the wrong approach).

Also, you don't need those base addresses in your Web.config.

Comment: Right now,I've finally landed on a error that says resource cannot be found....

Comment: That's not quite enough information.  Full stack trace and full error posted to your question would help a lot.

Comment: WebHost failed to process a request.

 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/WcfService1/Service1.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. 
Parameter name: item. ---> System.ArgumentException: This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. 
Parameter name: item

Comment: Thats the error on the eventviewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it works (I'm really not sure it will work for both addresses, but it might):

```
protected override System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        string baseAddress = string.Format("http://{0}{1}{2}", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port == 80 ? "" : ":" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port, HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath);
        Uri baseURI = new Uri(baseAddress);
        return base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, new Uri[] { baseURI });
    }

    //We did the best we could, but there is no current HTTP request.
    //Just fall back to the base service host factory
    return base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
}
```

It doesn't look like you have transport security on, so assuming "http://" is probably safe,  but if you need to turn that on, you'll have to tinker with the code to get the http**s**:// in there.

Comment: This didn't actually work.
Had no other way than to find a way to use through the same host name by changing our network configurations

Answer (score 0):

Hey, add this in your `<system.serviceModel>` config section

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

and

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class yourService : IyourService
{ ..... }
```

add `using System.ServiceModel.Activation;` to your code

I was having the same problem too.